# SSRS PBI report refresh error: [Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.OData.Core.NetFX35.V7`]

Tags: dll, reporting-services, odata, powerbi, power-bi-report-server

I have built a report in PBI Desktop and published to PBI Report Server.  The datasource connection type is ODATA.  The report will not update on the PBI Report Server.  What should I do to make the scheduled refresh work?

1. The report runs and refreshes just fine on my computer.
2. The report was successfully deployed to PBI Report Server and I can interact with the data & visuals just fine on the PBIRS.
3. The data source connection test says “successful”.
4. According to [MSDOCS: Power BI report data sources in Power BI Report Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/report-server/data-sources), the ODATA datasource it supported for “Scheduled Refreshed”; it is not a “Live” connection (like SQL datasource).

The problem is when I schedule the report to refresh in Report Manager the refresh fails and the data is not up-to-date with the datasource.

> The error message:
>
> > **Data source error: Login failed for data source ‘Unknown’.**
>
> The error details button displays this message:
>
> > **SessionID: d363d9d2-d9d3-4838-8241-d2cadcc59c73 [0] -1055784932: File
> >     or Folder: Could not load file or assembly
> >     'Microsoft.OData.Core.NetFX35.V7, Version=7.4.0.11102,
> >     Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its
> >     dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.. The
> >     exception was raised by the IDbCommand interface.**

I have attempted to execute the refresh with both a **`Report refresh`** and **`Shared Schedule refresh`** and I have also tried refreshing the connection via schedule ("Schedule"-- 2:00PM) and manual ("Refresh Now"-- 2:07PM).

I conducted a search on my desktop computer C: drive for the file seen in the error message (`Microsoft.OData.Core.NetFX35.V7`) and I did find the DLL file on my desktop pc in multiple different folder directories (screenshot below).  The DLL file is found on my desktop pc :C Drive in multiple locations. The DLL file is not found on the server directory. I don't know much of anything about DLL and Assemblies.

```
 - C:\Program Files\Microsoft Power BI Desktop\bin\ ... 1 files
 - C:\Program Files\Microsoft Power BI Desktop RS\bin\ ... 1 files
 - C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Power BI Desktop RS\bin\ ... 1 files
 - C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\ ... 2 files
 - C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\ ... 2 files
```

[image: Microsoft.OData.Core.NetFX35.V7.dll (GCOD050, Laptop) - server missing dll.png]

---

### **UPDATE 4/30/2019, DLL installation**

I tried installing the DLL manually.  I then tried installing the full PBI Desktop program.

**(Update 1) DLL Manual Install**

I tried installing the DLL manually, but I ran into some command-line errors (regsvr32, regasm).

References: [Install DLL File in Windows](https://lifehacker.com/install-a-dll-file-in-windows-269063) / [MsDocs> .NET Framework> Regasm.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/regasm-exe-assembly-registration-tool)

[image: DLL command line error messages.png]

**(Update 2) PBI Desktop program install**

I then tried installing the full PBI Desktop program.  The DLL file is now found on the server directories.  But the refresh error message persists... :  "**...`Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.OData.Core.NetFX35.V7, Version=7.4.0.11102, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies.... The system cannot find the file specified.`**".

Server directories:

```
 C:\Program Files\Microsoft Power BI Desktop RS\bin\ ... 1 files
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Power BI Desktop RS\bin\ ... 1 files
 C:\Program Data\Microsoft\NetFramework\BreadcrumbStore\ ... 2 files
 ...  Microsoft.OData.Core.NetFX35.V7, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
 ...  Microsoft.OData.Core.NetFX35.V7, Version=7.4.0.11102, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
 C:\Users\All Users\Microsoft\NetFramework\BreadcrumbStore\ ... 1 files
 ...  Microsoft.OData.Core.NetFX35.V7, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
 ...  Microsoft.OData.Core.NetFX35.V7, Version=7.4.0.11102, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
 C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\ ... 2 files
 C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\ ... 2 files
```

[image: Microsoft.OData.Core.NetFX35.V7.dll (GCOD050, Laptop) - directories.png]

---

### **REPORT SERVER (screenshots: data source, schedule refresh)**

**DATA SOURCE**

Here is the configuration of the datasource properties at the report manager URL.

> http://gcod050/reports/manage/catalogitem/datasources/01-PBI/SSRS%20Datasets
>
> [image]

**DATASOURCE REFRESH ERROR**

[image]

Comment: Seems to be a permission problem, check with any proxy setting you might consider by asking network administrator.  What is location for your ODATA source?

Comment: **What is location for your ODATA source?** --> http://gcod050/reports/api/v2.0

Comment: @Mboolean, The windows account I am using to authenticate the datasource is Administrator on the server.  To my knowledge, that would rule out a permissions issue.  What question would I pose the network admins?  Thanks for your help

Comment: Can you please add datasource tab picture if possible?

Comment: @Mboolean, Added screenshot of configuration for datasource at the report manager URL.